# Access VBA: How to change the query timeout when setting RecordSource

Tags: vba, ms-access, timeout, ms-access-2010

In Access 2010 I have a form with a subform. Via VBA I create a SQL query and set the RecordSource of the subform to run the query and show the results:

```
Forms("<main form>")("<subform>").Form.RecordSource = my_sql_sentence
```

Sometimes, the query produces a timeout error, so I detect it:

```
On Error Resume Next
Forms("<main form>")("<subform>").Form.RecordSource = my_sql_sentence
If Err <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Error! (probably timeout): " & Err.Description
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```

The timeout seems to be ~ 1 minute. I have tried to change the time for timeout by setting the QueryTimeout property of the CurrentDB object before changing the RecordSource property:

```
CurrentDb.QueryTimeout = 2
On Error Resume Next
Forms("<main form>")("<subform>").Form.RecordSource = my_sql_sentence
If Err <> 0 Then
...
```

but it doesn't work, timeout is still 60.

If I try to change the timeout in the Inmediate panel, it has no effect:

```
? CurrentDB.QueryTimeout
 60 
CurrentDB.QueryTimeout = 2
? CurrentDB.QueryTimeout
 60
```

How can I change the timeout for the SQL query that is run when I set the RecordSource property of a form?

---

**Update**: Solved: There is a way to set the timeout for queries on ODBC connections (I use ODBC connection to Oracle). The SQL sencentes that I'm assigning to the RecordSource don't use a linked table, they use an Access query object. I mean that the SQL sentences are not like "select * from my_linked_oracle_table ...", they are more like "select * from my_access_query_object ...". So I can set the timeout for the QueryDef that corresponds to the Access query object, in this way:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("<my_access_query_object>").ODBCTimeout = 120
```

that sets 2 minutes as timeout for the Access query object used by my SQL queries.

So now I set the timeout and then change the RecordSource property of the subform:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("<my_access_query_object>").ODBCTimeout = 120
Forms("<main form>")("<subform>").Form.RecordSource = my_sql_sentence
```

Comment: +1 for the Update which is a helpful solution.  Adding as Community Wiki since this user is apparently not active in SO.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to set the timeout for queries on ODBC connections (I use ODBC connection to Oracle). The SQL sencentes that I'm assigning to the RecordSource don't use a linked table, they use an Access query object. I mean that the SQL sentences are not like "select * from my_linked_oracle_table ...", they are more like "select * from my_access_query_object ...". So I can set the timeout for the QueryDef that corresponds to the Access query object, in this way:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("<my_access_query_object>").ODBCTimeout = 120
```

that sets 2 minutes as timeout for the Access query object used by my SQL queries.

So now I set the timeout and then change the RecordSource property of the subform:

```
CurrentDb.QueryDefs("<my_access_query_object>").ODBCTimeout = 120
Forms("<main form>")("<subform>").Form.RecordSource = my_sql_sentence
```

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this, there might be something helpfull:

http://www.geeksengine.com/article/how-to-change-timeout-value-for-access-sql.html

Comment: I solved it with the ODBCTimeout property of the QueryDef (see the "Update" section of the question).